# Unhelpful iOS Crash Logs from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

We've been running into a couple weird crashes involving MapKit, specifically `mapView.setRegion(_ region:, animated:)` and the crash logs that were saved are weird and very unhelpful. They seem to reference memory locations rather than lines of code (exception backtrace lines 4,5 and thread 0 lines 7, 13, 14). Noticeably gone from the `.xccrashpoint` file are DSYMs even though debug info is set to DWARF with DSYM. The `.xccrashpoint` file does not open in xCode. Note that the crash logs are from an iPhone X device as that specific tester is experiencing the crash and I cannot replicate it. Can someone help me make sense of these crash logs, or give me an up to date way to make them make sense?

```
Date/Time:           2018-07-23 13:06:11.8890 -0400
Launch Time:         2018-07-23 13:05:56.6991 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    1.04.80
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1819b6d8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x180b705ec objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1819b69f0 -[NSException raise] + 12 (NSException.m:98)
3   MapKit                          0x192814de4 -[MKMapView setRegion:animated:] + 596 (MKMapView.m:8360)
4   Local                           0x102e2616c 0x102df4000 + 205164
5   Local                           0x102ebc394 0x102df4000 + 820116
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1812a8aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1812a8a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:507)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1812e9d80 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 964 (inline_internal.h:2500)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18195f070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x18195cbc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272 (CFRunLoop.c:3111)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x18187cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
12  GraphicsServices                0x183862020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
13  UIKit                           0x18b89c758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
14  Local                           0x102dfef80 0x102df4000 + 44928
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x18130dfc0 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018143d2e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001815e26a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001813abdb0 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001813abd18 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180b472c8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:75)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180b47470 default_terminate_handler() + 304 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:68)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180b708d4 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:657)
7   Local                           0x0000000102ee932c 0x102df4000 + 1004332
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180b6137c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180b60ccc __cxa_throw + 132 (cxa_exception.cpp:130)
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180b70720 objc_exception_throw + 364 (objc-exception.mm:547)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001819b69f0 -[NSException raise] + 12 (NSException.m:98)
12  MapKit                          0x0000000192814de4 -[MKMapView setRegion:animated:] + 596 (MKMapView.m:8360)
13  Local                           0x0000000102e2616c 0x102df4000 + 205164
14  Local                           0x0000000102ebc394 0x102df4000 + 820116
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001812a8aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001812a8a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:507)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001812e9d80 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 964 (inline_internal.h:2500)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018195f070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1815)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018195cbc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272 (CFRunLoop.c:3111)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018187cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
21  GraphicsServices                0x0000000183862020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
22  UIKit                           0x000000018b89c758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
23  Local                           0x0000000102dfef80 0x102df4000 + 44928
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018130dfc0 start + 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to get the proper dSYM for your own app so the symbolicated crash log shows where it crashed within your own code.

Comment: Google “symbolicate”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong folder in the .xccrashpoint package. There was a subfolder labeled "Locally Symbolicated" in which there was a symbolicated .crash file.
[Subfolder with symbolicated crashlog highlighted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i48g.png)